# Could not find runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

After I am running `ionic cordova build android` I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
  https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/1.0.0/runtime-1.0.0.jar
```

And it is right. When I go to this URL `https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/1.0.0/runtime-1.0.0.jar` I get an `404 Not found error` as a JSON.

I don't see any android/ cordova specific versions in that URL so I can't say its from my cordova installation.

Cordova version: `7.1.0`

Ionic info:

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\%User%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed // this is strange. I can run cordova in my terminal tho

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v8.4.0
    npm               : 5.3.0
    OS                : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\%User%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Also, I don't have any `cordova-android`  folders in `C:\Users\%USER%\.cordova\lib\npm_cache` (I don't know if this helps. I saw people talking about this folder)

What's the problem here? Where is that URL coming from? How can I change it and with what can I change it?

If I cannot solve this easily there is one last step to do: remove and install everything again.

Thank you!

Comment: I have this problem on React Native after running react-native run-android command.

Comment: As I can see there a many people with the exact same problem in the exact same day. It may be a temporary problem with the CDN servers?

Comment: @boyd yep, looks like someone decided to break everyones builds

Comment: You may try compileSdkVersion upgrade.

Comment: I messaged the guys from `jcenter`. They said there is no `.jar` file there. It's only a `.aar` file.

Comment: ohh, so no permanent solution like without editing build.gradle manually for Cordova user?

Comment: Looks like this solves a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944600/4255978

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A quick temporary fix is to include the google maven repo in your top level gradle file.

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
      mavenLocal()
      maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } // <-- add this!
      jcenter()
```

Comment: Yes it's a great solution and it's logic.
Bintray has a problem with the lib, so download from another host.
Thanks

Comment: https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/1.0.0/runtime-1.0.0.jar    

This is the repo its looking for. Any alternate solution.?

Comment: @JItendraRana: make sure you edit your-react-native-project/android/build.gradle and add the new line before jcenter and in the allprojects group.

Comment: After trying this, gradle is unable to find following file `https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.1.0/aapt2-proto-0.1.0.jar` - some dependency for `react-native-firebase`

Comment: I am working on a react-native project now I can build the project but can't start the app it prompts "Unfortunately, app has stopped"

Comment: The order here is very important. Make sure that `jcenter()` comes **after** `maven`. Otherwise, it will try `jcenter()` first and keep failing.

Answer (score 13):

For me [AIT MANSOUR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50564539/2284676) and [Moritz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50564412/2284676) answers didn't work, because I had other dependencies that required `jcenter()` and `jitpack`, additionally, for `react-native` you need the `node_modules`.

So, my solution for `react-native` is

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // this is for native modules I'm developing
        mavenLocal()
        // for modules depending on jitpack.io
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        // add this one
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        // keep this at the end
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me with react-native.

Use npm packages they said, it's easy they said.
Wasted HOURS with this!!

Thanks octohedron!

Comment: Worked like a treat. By ordering your repositories like this you're essentially pulling libraries from Maven first, then your local node_modules directory and then anything that's not in those two will be pulled from jcenter. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, here is a link to a popular Github Issue on the same error: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/748

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem (at least for me).

It seems that the `jcenter` has some issues providing the libraries for the project(it may be temporary). As people suggested here, you can solve this by getting those libraries from maven.

Go to your build.gradle file (for ionic devs it is in /platforms/android) and add above every line of code where says `jcenter()` this line `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }`.

For me it was is two places: `buildscript` and `allprojects`. At the end the top of your build.gradle file should look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

What it does? It just changes the libraries provider(in this case jcenter) with another one so your app can download them successfully. Every line in there is a  libraries provider with fallback.

I don't know why it didn't fallback to maven in the first place because the fallback provider was in my build.gradle file.

Comment: It is a temporary fix so we can work. Maybe tomorrow the `jcenter` will be available.

Comment: I think the reason it doesn't "fallback to maven" is because it's finding a listing in jcenter but it's not finding the needed `.jar` file. So it's "there" but the specific `.jar` file it needs is not, which is different than if jcenter didn't have a listing for it. According to jcenter, they only have the `.aar` file for this library, not the `.jar`.

Comment: In my case, the jcenter () statement was above maven and so my application was crashing. This tip solved the problem!

Answer (score 4):

This morning I Had the same problem :

```
    Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
```

> Could not find runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0).
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/1.0.0/runtime-1.0.0.j

I fixed it this way : 
On Project repository, i edit build.gradle, i commented jcenter()  :

```
repositories {
   // jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

Now the project is building successfully ! 
Good luck !

Comment: in which gradle app/build.gradle or build.gradle??

Comment: No need to comment it out, as you might require libraries that are only available on `jcenter()`. You can just move it below `maven`. However, if you comment it out and it works, that probably means you can remove `jcenter()` entirely because you're likely not depending on any libraries from that repository.

Answer (score 4):

In android/build.gradle, change the code as -

```
   allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this in my React-Native projects.
Not working.

Comment: can share your project?

Comment: @JItendraRana Try moving `jcenter()` to the bottom of the list, after you "node_modules" `maven` listing.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the issue is that the pom is listed on jcenter but the jar is missing.

https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/1.0.0/

Gradle will fail if the metadata is present in a repo but the artifact is missing

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1120

@Moritz's fix should work by going to maven.google.com first

Answer (score 1):

This is work for me just follow these two step

**Step 1:** In project **build.gradle** file just replace the code below

```
 allprojects {
      repositories {
          mavenLocal()
          maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
          jcenter()
//        google()
    }
}
```

Just comment the ***google()*** if exist in your project gradle file.

**Step 2:** In file **gradle-wrapper.properties** downgrade the ***distributionUrl*** i have just downgrade with the below.

```
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-all.zip
```

Comment: I don't think the `gradle-wrapper.properties` has anything to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

A new version of `cordova-android` (7.1.1) has been released that solves this problem.

So remove current android platform

```
cordova platform rm android
```

And add the new platform

```
cordova platform add android@7.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed android platform and then added it again:
to remove:

cordova platform rm android

to add:

cordova platform add android

and all works fine now
Note: this version of android didn't install properly this time (did before today!)

cordova platform add android@6.1.0