# Artifactory is missing android dependencies

Tags: artifactory

Related to [Could not find runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563338/could-not-find-runtime-jar-android-arch-lifecycleruntime1-0-0)

Artifactory (https://repo.jfrog.org/) is missing multiple (all?) Android dependencies affecting (at least) Cordova and React Native builds today. Anyone know what the cause could be, or where an issue can be registered?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with their repository. You can see that by refreshing a directory listing of dependency multiple times. A lot of times the directory list is empty: https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/com/android/tools/build/gradle/