# gradle build failed in Ionic App

Tags: ionic3

I get this error today when i'm trying to build an app called wired brain. I have followed a tutorial but I notice that gradle build is failed.

the error is detailed in belowed Logs:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
            * What went wrong:
            A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
            > Could not find common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.0.0).
            Searched in the following locations:
                https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/core/common/1.0.0/common-1.0.0.jar

            * Try:
            Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
            Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
            FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

            * What went wrong:
            A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
            > Could not find common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.0.0).
            Searched in the following locations:
                https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/core/common/1.0.0/common-1.0.0.jar

            * Try:
            Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

            [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).
```

This error is occured when I run this command: ionic cordova run android

that's my gradle:

```
            /*
                Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
                or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
                distributed with this work for additional information
                regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
                to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
                "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
                with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

                    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

                Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
                software distributed under the License is distributed on an
                "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
                KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
                specific language governing permissions and limitations
                under the License.
            */

            apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

            buildscript {
                repositories {
                    jcenter()
                    maven {
                        url "https://maven.google.com"
                    }
                }

                // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
                // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
                // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
                // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
                dependencies {
                    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
                }
            }

            // Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
            allprojects {
                repositories {
                    jcenter()
                    maven {
                        url "https://maven.google.com"
                    }
                }
            }

            task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
                gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
            }

            // Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
            // Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
            ext {
                apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
                // The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
                if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
                    cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
                }
                // The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
                if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
                    cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
                }
                // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
                if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
                    cdvVersionCode = null
                }
                // Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
                if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
                    cdvMinSdkVersion = null
                }
                // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
                if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
                    cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
                }
                // .properties files to use for release signing.
                if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
                    cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
                }
                // .properties files to use for debug signing.
                if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
                    cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
                }
                // Set by build.js script.
                if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
                    cdvBuildArch = null
                }

                // Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
                cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
            }

            // PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
            apply from: "cordova-plugin-fcm/android-FCMPlugin.gradle"
            // PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

            def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
            if (hasBuildExtras) {
                apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
            }

            // Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
            if (ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion == null) {
                ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
            }
            if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
                ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
            }
            if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
                ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = 'debug-signing.properties'
            }
            if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('release-signing.properties').exists()) {
                ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = 'release-signing.properties'
            }

            // Cast to appropriate types.
            ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
            ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
            ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

            def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
                def ret = 'assemble'
                if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
                    def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
                    ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
                }
                return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
            }

            // Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
            task cdvBuildDebug
            cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
                return computeBuildTargetName(true)
            }

            task cdvBuildRelease
            cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
                return computeBuildTargetName(false)
            }

            task cdvPrintProps << {
                println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
                println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
                println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
                println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
                println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
                println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
                println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
                println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
                println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
                android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
                    println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
                }
            }

            android {
                sourceSets {
                    main {
                        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                        java.srcDirs = ['src']
                        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                        res.srcDirs = ['res']
                        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
                        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
                    }
                }

                defaultConfig {
                    versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
                    applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

                    if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
                        minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
                    }
                }

                lintOptions {
                abortOnError false;
                }

                compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion

                if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
                    productFlavors {
                        armv7 {
                            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
                            ndk {
                                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
                            }
                        }
                        x86 {
                            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
                            ndk {
                                abiFilters "x86", ""
                            }
                        }
                        all {
                            ndk {
                                abiFilters "all", ""
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                /*

                ELSE NOTHING! DON'T MESS WITH THE VERSION CODE IF YOU DON'T HAVE TO!

                else if (!cdvVersionCode) {
                def minSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion ?: privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("minSdkVersion")
                // Vary versionCode by the two most common API levels:
                // 14 is ICS, which is the lowest API level for many apps.
                // 20 is Lollipop, which is the lowest API level for the updatable system webview.
                if (minSdkVersion >= 20) {
                    defaultConfig.versionCode += 9
                } else if (minSdkVersion >= 14) {
                    defaultConfig.versionCode += 8
                }
                }
                */

                compileOptions {
                    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
                    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
                }

                if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
                    signingConfigs {
                        release {
                            // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                            keyAlias = ""
                            keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                            storeFile = null
                            storePassword = "__unset"
                        }
                    }
                    buildTypes {
                        release {
                            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                        }
                    }
                    addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
                }
                if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
                    addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
                }
            }

            dependencies {
                compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
                // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
                debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
                releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
                compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+"
                compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+"
                // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
            }

            def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
                if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
                    return;
                }
                if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
                    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
                }
                if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
                    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
                }
            }

            gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
                taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
                    if (task.name == 'validateReleaseSigning' || task.name == 'validateSigningRelease') {
                        promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
                    }
                }
            }

            def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
                def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
                def props = new Properties()
                propsFile.withReader { reader ->
                    props.load(reader)
                }

                def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
                if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
                    storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
                }
                if (!storeFile.exists()) {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
                }
                signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
                signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
                signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
                signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
                def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
                if (!storeType) {
                    def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
                    if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
                        storeType = 'pkcs12'
                    } else {
                        storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
                    }
                }
                signingConfig.storeType = storeType
            }

            for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
                func()
            }

            // This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
            //     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
            if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
                postBuildExtras()
            }
```

please any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/50564412/137259

Ensure your /platforms/android/build.gradle has:

`allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } //this line must be above jcenter()
        jcenter()
    }
}`